# How do I declare a vector in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, vector

How do you write a vector in OpenCV? that contains 3 values like this `v = [p1,p2,p3]`? This is what I tried:

```
int dim [1] = {3};
Mat v(1,dim,CV_32F, Scalar(p1,p2,p3));
```

But when I do debug in Qt, I see in the local and expression window that the vector `v` indeed has 1 column and 3 rows but has also 2 dim. I was wondering if this is due to the `Mat` type in the declaration.
With which type could I replace it to get just a simple vector of 3 values?

Comment: `cv::Scalar` is already a vector of 4 elements. You can use `cv::Vec_`, or `std::vector` also. `Mat` is a 2D vector, a matrix indeed. But you need to specify how you intend to use this, or it's simply a too broad question.

Comment: A simple vector of 3 values (e.g. `double`) can be: `cv::Vec3d v(p1, p2, p3);` or `std::vector<double> v{p1, p2, p3};`

Comment: thank you for responding, i want to do some operation on this vector like use the norm and change it's element

Comment: @Miki how to access element of this vector ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which type could I use to get just a simple vector of 3 values? I want to do some operation on this vector like use the norm and change it's elements.

You can use [cv::Vec](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec) type.

Assuming you're working on `double` values (the same applies for other types) you can:

```
// Create a vector
Vec3d v;

// Assign values / Change elements
v[0] = 1.1;
v[1] = 2.2;
v[2] = 3.3;

// Or initialize in the constructor directly 
Vec3d u(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);

// Read values
double d0 = v[0];

// Compute the norm, using cv::norm 
double norm_L2 = norm(v, NORM_L2); // or norm(v);
double norm_L1 = norm(v, NORM_L1);
```

---

For:

- `double` type use `Vec3d`
- `float` type use `Vec3f`
- `int` type use `Vec3i`
- `short` type use `Vec3s`
- `ushort` type use `Vec3w`
- `uchar` type use `Vec3b`

Comment: what about  CV_8SC3  ?  should it be cv::Vec3b?

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/6ae8103022cdb3cd79f417945fd8332c28298b7b/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp#L406-L436) there is no typedef for `char`. You can make your own, like: `typedef Vec<char, 3> Vec3c;`

Comment: Yeah it works, what about CV_16FC3, CV_16FC1  how can I define this on my own ?

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer The same, but instead of `char` put the type corresponding to float16 (which is not available in the C++ standard)